# Cloudflare CNAME issue

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I purchased a domain name from Cloudflare. example.com
I created a CNAME records

> name= remote, target=https:railway.io/serverID

This works perfect

The issue is that I need to create another CNAME record but I get the following error

> DNS Validation Error (Code: 1004) Content for CNAME record is invalid

I pressed add records:

> name= images, target=https://imagestroagebucket.com

These are not the real targets but I have issue with trying to add a second CNAME

I am trying to add a CNAME for BackBlaze cloud b2 storage

Comment: Hover over the dns tag and read that pop-up. Then delete this please

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare [says](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/dns-record-types/#cname) that CNAME target should be [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).
That means you should not to add http or https to the target.